# scroll spy not working on chrome

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `div` inside it different `div`s containing each section with unique ids as follows:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top edit-1" id="uniqueID">
    <div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class=""><a href="#Contact" data-scroll="">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="info active"><a href="#infoTab" data-scroll="">Key Information</a></li>
                <li class="initialHiddenfields" style="display: none;"><a href="#Production1" data-scroll="">Production1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So want to implement "Scroll spy" of bootstrap using jquery. I am using following code in js:

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#uniqueID' });
```

it is working on Firefox but not working on Chrome. Please suggest what could be the reason even I am not getting any error.

Comment: nothing with php, html and jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check this its working in chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
            position: relative; 
            }
            #section1 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
            #section2 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
            #section3 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
            #section41 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
            #section42 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top edit-1" id="uniqueID">
            <div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class=""><a href="#Contact" data-scroll="">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="info active"><a href="#infoTab" data-scroll="">Key Information</a></li>
                        <li class="initialHiddenfields" style="display: none;"><a href="#infoTab" data-scroll="">Production1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="Contact" class="container-fluid">
            <h1>Section 1</h1>
            <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
            <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="infoTab" class="container-fluid">
            <h1>Section 2</h1>
            <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
            <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Production1" class="container-fluid">
            <h1>Section 3</h1>
            <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
            <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: its working in chrome. but In my project not working, even not getting any error, what might be issue. can u please see

Comment: its working now. thanks. I have included latest bootstrap files js and css

Comment: In my pproject i have already included latest bootstrap and jquery. then why its not working. if I include these above libs then it works why?

Comment: jquery 2.1.4  and boostrap 3.3.6

Comment: I have added this two lib its working fine you need to check this.

Comment: <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top header-top"> its there in my code

Comment: I try compiled bootstrap .css its not working for me so i tried above css and js of bootstrap and it will work fine.

Comment: /*!
* Bootstrap v3.3.6 (http://getbootstrap.com)
* Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
* Licensed under the MIT license
*/
/*! jQuery v2.1.4 | (c) 2005, 2015 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */  These are exact version of bootstrap and jquery we are using

Comment: I mean to say that I have already Latest jquery and Bootstrap versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113514/discussion-between-niketan-raval-and-user3458514).

Answer (score 0):

You need to target on class not on id like.

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.navbar' });
```